# LoadError in ProductsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the follwing happened while running the application
I am also not able to install therubyracer gem to ruby

```
cannot load such file -- v8 (in C:/railsapps/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
Extracted source (around line #10):

8 <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
9 <![endif]-->
10  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
11
12
13  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Do you have `application.css` file in your `app/assets`?

Comment: yeh i have that file in my directory

Comment: Remove this file `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`

Comment: I removed it
The Following happened
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Products#index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SASS**

This issue will likely be caused by importing (requiring) that particular file in your CSS

If you use one of the SASS `@import` functions like this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
@import "name"
```

The problem here is that, like in other programming interfaces, if you call a file which doesn't exist, it will throw an error. If this happens, you'll typically receive an error like the one you're seeing (I.E "could not find" etc etc)

--

**Fix**

Without seeing your `application.css.less`, I can only speculate on what the answer might be. I would recommend:

> 1. Make sure you have the following file present (even if empty): `app/assets/stylehsheets/bootstrap_and_override.css.less`
> 2. With the file present, you should then be able to load it. If not, you need to find the reference to `@import` in your
>      `application.css.less` file

Comment: I did the thing you told me to do
the following happened!|
couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'

Comment: Okay so you're using twitter bootstrap - do you have the gem installed & have you followed the [instructions](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)?

Comment: yeh i installed||  rails g bootstrap:install

Comment: And it's still not working? Have you included the bootstrap files in your `application.rb`?

Comment: yeh i added the line in application.rb but the error is continuing 
i added this line in application.rb||  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)